# How to use an array as index in a 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Hi I have loaded an image, thus creating a 3D matrix.

```
img1 = imread('bluebird.jpg')
```

I know that for a vector, i can create another vector based on a logic test and use this other vector as index like this:

```
speeds = [20 77 55 90 87 65 67 72 55]
invalid = speed > 70
speeds(invalid) = 0
```

This will set all invalid speed in `speeds` to 0.

But I have not figured out how to do it with a 3D matrix (an image).

What I want to do is swap color components 1 (red) and 3 (blue) for every pixel where the blue component is at least 20% higher than the average of the three components (the gray scale).

I have tried this:

```
img1 = imread('bluebird.jpg');
img2 = img1;
m = mean(img1, 3);
blues = img1(:,:,3) > 1.2*m;
img2(blues, [3,2,1]) = img1(blues, [1,2,3]);
```

But that did not work. The variable blues successfully get the pixels I want (the ones with a dominant blue component), but I get a illegal syntax on the last line.

Is it possible to do what I want? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because your logical array is 2D (takes care of the first two dimensions) and your linear index is only applied to the third dimension. You *can* combine logical indices however you must have one array of either  *per-dimension*.

```
data = magic(3);
data([true false, true], [1 3])

%   8   6
%   4   2
```

An easy way around this for your case is to reshape your input to an `[M*N x 3]` array and then you can do exactly what you want because your logical array will now be a column vector of length `M*N`.

```
img1 = imread('bluebird.jpg');

% Remember the original size
shape = size(img1);

% Reshape to (M*N x 3)
img2 = reshape(img1, [], 3);

isBlue = img2(:,3) > 1.2 * mean(img2, 2);
img2(isBlue, [3 2 1]) = img2(isBlue, [1 2 3]);

% Reshape it back to the original size
img2 = reshape(img2, shape);
```

Or rather than using indexing, you could simply call `fliplr`.

```
img1 = imread('bluebird.jpg');

% Remember the original size
shape = size(img1);

% Reshape to (M*N x 3)
img2 = reshape(img1, [], 3);

isBlue = img2(:,3) > 1.2 * mean(img2, 2);
img2(isBlue, :) = fliplr(img2(isBlue, :));

% Reshape it back to the original size
img2 = reshape(img2, shape);
```

This is going to be more performant than creating a 3D logical matrix because `reshape` commands are very cheap as they don't actually alter the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

Logical indexing (using matrices) and indexing by integers cannot be mixed.
Instead, you can construct full logical index matrices:

```
img2 = rand(2, 4, 3);
m = mean(img2, 3);
blues = img2(:,:,3) > 1.2*m;
f_ind = false(size(blues));
ind = cat(3, blues, f_ind, blues);
img2(ind) = cat(3, img2(cat(3, f_ind, f_ind, blues)), img2(cat(3, blues, f_ind, f_ind)));
```

Or, instead of the last two lines:

```
r_ind = cat(3, blues, f_ind, f_ind);
b_ind = cat(3, f_ind, f_ind, blues);
img2(b_ind) = img1(r_ind);
img2(r_ind) = img1(b_ind);
```

Comment: That first statement isn't actually true. You just can't combine logical *matrices* and integer-based indexing.

Comment: @Suever thanks for the clarification. And 'integer-based' is the correct term, too...

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[Y,X] = find(blues);
inds1 = sub2ind(size(img1),Y,X,ones(length(Y),1));
inds2 = sub2ind(size(img1),Y,X,3*ones(length(Y),1));
img2([inds1,inds2]) = img1([inds2,inds1]);
```

Comment: Hi. I tried your code and the image displayed was identical to the original image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I fixed it (had a small typo)